# Layering a feathered image overtop of a non-feathered image in ImageMagick to hide feathering

Tags: bash, imagemagick, overlay, layer

I am seeking to disguise feathering by putting a non-feathered version of my image underneath the feathered version. These two images need to be perfectly aligned, and are the exact same size.

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible? Would this ImageMagick command, run in bash, accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
 composite -geometry  +0+0 large_feathered.png large.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is what I am trying to accomplish possible?

Yes

> Would this ImageMagick command, run in bash, accomplish what I am trying to do?
>
> ```
> composite -geometry  +0+0 large_feathered.png large.png
> ```

Almost, but you might get the error message...

> composite:  `large.png' @ error/composite.c/CompositeImageCommand/1616.

This is because you're missing the destination path. Try...

```
composite -geometry +0+0 large_feathered.png large.png result.png
```

However, the `+0+0` is the default value for `-geometry`, so you may be able to reduce the statement down to...

```
composite large_feathered.png large.png result.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!